# Change MergedDictionaries at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, themes, scrollbar

I'm currently working on a WPF application that allows the user to change its theme during runtime (without any restart). I'm currently using the code from here:

http://svetoslavsavov.blogspot.de/2009/07/switching-wpf-interface-themes-at.html

I modified it with a `Try` statement:

```
private static void ApplyTheme(FrameworkElement targetElement, Uri dictionaryUri)
    {
        if (targetElement == null) return;

        try
        {
            ResourceDictionary themeDictionary = null;
            if (dictionaryUri != null)
            {
                themeDictionary = new ResourceDictionary();
                themeDictionary.Source = dictionaryUri;

                targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Insert(0, themeDictionary);
            }

            List<ResourceDictionary> existingDictionaries =
                (from dictionary in targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.OfType<ResourceDictionary>()
                 select dictionary).ToList();

            foreach (ResourceDictionary thDictionary in existingDictionaries)
            {
                if (themeDictionary == thDictionary) continue;
                try
                {
                    targetElement.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(thDictionary);
                }
                catch { }
            }
        }
        finally { }
    }
```

But it doesn't really work if I have styled ScrollBars in my application. The first time it always turns the same ComboBox into a rectangle and you can't use it anymore:

http://goo.gl/eNC2m0

The second time it throws an exception:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate'.
```

If I remove the `Try` statement, it already throws the exception on the first time.

The ScrollBar style looks like this:

```
<!-- Colors -->
<Color x:Key="Accent">#FFFEB809</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource Accent}"/>
<Color x:Key="AccentConsole">#22FEB809</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentConsoleBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentConsole}"/>
<Color x:Key="AccentLight">#FFFFDB82</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentLightBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentLight}"/>
<Color x:Key="AccentLightConsole">#22FFDB82</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentLightConsoleBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentLightConsole}"/>
<Color x:Key="AccentText">#FFFFFFFF</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AccentTextBrush" Color="{StaticResource AccentText}"/>
<Color x:Key="Border">#FFCCCCCC</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush" Color="{StaticResource Border}"/>
<Color x:Key="CaptionBar">#FFFCFCFC</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="CaptionBarBrush" Color="{StaticResource CaptionBar}"/>
<Color x:Key="ConsoleBackground">#FF222222</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ConsoleBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource ConsoleBackground}"/>
<Color x:Key="ControlBackground">White</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ControlBackgroundBrush" Color="{StaticResource ControlBackground}"/>
<Color x:Key="NavigationHeader">#88000000</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="NavigationHeaderBrush" Color="{StaticResource NavigationHeader}"/>
<Color x:Key="Window">#FFFAFAFA</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="WindowBrush" Color="{StaticResource Window}"/>

<Style x:Key="{x:Type ScrollBar}" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBar}"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="24"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="HorizontalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="#22000000" CornerRadius="4">
            <Track Name="PART_Track">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageLeftCommand"/>
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <!-- The problem occurs here -->
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarThumb}"/>
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageRightCommand"/>
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="#22000000" CornerRadius="4">
            <Track Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand"/>
                </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <Track.Thumb>
                    <!-- The problem occurs here -->
                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarThumb}"/>
                </Track.Thumb>
                <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand"/>
                </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
            </Track>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<Style x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="24"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource LeftScrollBarLineButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand"/>
                    <Border Name="Base" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Foreground="#FF585858" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource RightScrollBarLineButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" Grid.Column="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="VerticalScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="24"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource TopScrollBarLineButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineUpCommand"/>
                    <Border Name="Base" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,0,1,0" Grid.Row="1">
                        <TextBlock Text="" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Foreground="#FF585858" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                    <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource BottomScrollBarLineButton}" Command="ScrollBar.LineDownCommand" Grid.Row="2"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="LeftScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Base" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="4,0,0,4" BorderThickness="1,1,0,1">
                    <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Base" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentLight}" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlBackground}" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="RightScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Base" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0,4,4,0" BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                    <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Base" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="90"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentLight}" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlBackground}" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="TopScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Base" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="4,4,0,0" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0">
                    <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Base" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentLight}" Offset="0"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlBackground}" Offset="1"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="BottomScrollBarLineButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Base" Background="{StaticResource ControlBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource BorderBrush}" CornerRadius="0,0,4,4" BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                    <TextBlock Text="" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Base" Property="Background">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource AccentLight}" Offset="1"/>
                                    <GradientStop Color="{StaticResource ControlBackground}" Offset="0"/>
                                </LinearGradientBrush>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton" TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF585858"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Semibold"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="8"/>
    <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

But when I replace `<Thumb Style="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarThumb}"/>` and `<Thumb Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBarThumb}"/>` with `<Thumb/>` it works.

I just can't find anything in the Thumb styles that could cause this problem.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the order of templates. Just change the order of the templates as given in following image. StaticResources should be parsed before it is referred in XAML.

[image]

Also the XAML code you pasted above missing some brush resources like AccentLight,ControlBackgroundBrush. I don't know whether those resources defined in your application in the proper hierarchy. Check that also.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! And the colors are defined. Sorry, I forgot them.